# Changing a version in iTunes connect before it goes live

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store, itunes-app

I have an app that has been submitted to the app store in iTunes connect and approved but not yet released. (The release date is set in the future). The version number is 1.0.0.

Before the app was to be released my client decided he wanted some changes made. So I added a version 1.0.1 and submitted it to the app store. It has also been approved and not released.

My client has yet again decided he wanted some changes made. I have now made version 1.0.2. I can now no longer add a version in iTunes connect, because 1.0.1 has not been released yet.

My client wants to release the app next week to coincide with a marketing campaign. I want plan to release 1.0.1 in iTunes connect and submit 1.0.2.

My questions are:

1. When I release 1.0.1 will it go into the app store? I think (and want) not, because the release date of the app is still set for the future, but I want to be sure.
2. An alternative would be to remove 1.0.1 altogether, but I see no way to do this. Is the way that I originally described the appropriate way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, as soon as you release, either automatically or manually, it will push out live to the App Store.
2. I'm not sure if you can remove an update that already been accepted and approved. My suggestion would be to release it quietly and submit your update for 1.0.2 right away. With the wait time around 5-6 business days, you don't have a large window if you want to meet your clients deadline for the marketing campaign.

Comment: I did release, and it seems that it hasn't actually gone live to the app store. In the rights and pricing section, it still lists the availability date as a future date, and I haven't seen the app in the app store yet. Basically version 1.0.1 replaced 1.0.0 and I was able to submit 1.0.2. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Good to know. Wasn't sure how the future date stuff worked. Glad you were able to get your next update ready to go.